# Adding bullets into a text placeholder in python-pptx

Tags: python-pptx

I'd like to take a list of sentences and add them as bullets into a text placeholder in python-pptx.
However, it turns out that the textplaceholder doesn't have an add_paragraph method, that could have done the job for a text box. any solutions for that, or should I dump the textplaceholder and use a textbox?
Thanks,
JT

Answer (score 0):

A placeholder is a shape, much like a textbox is a shape. A text (bullet) placeholder has a `.text_frame` property that works the same way as the one for a textbox. See the example in the documentation here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#bullet-slide-example

If this doesn't work, chances are good the shape is not a text placeholder. If that's the case, elaborate your question with the code you're using so we can see more precisely what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To see the `bullets` into a text placeholder in `python-pptx`. it would help if you chose the correct layout like `idx=1`, `idx=6` has no `Bullets`

```py
prs = Presentation()
bullet_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[1]
```

and add a paragraph like

```py
text_box = slide.placeholders[1].text_frame
paragraph1 = text_box.add_paragraph()
paragraph1.level = 1
paragraph1.text = "This is the first paragraph"
```